# Custom NET CORE CLI tool does not run on build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-cli

I have written a small test tool

```
namespace dotnet_cqsgen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\test.txt", "Hello");

        }
    }
}
```

Published it to a local nuget repo and added this to a host core project

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-cqsgen" Version="1.0.3" />    
  </ItemGroup>
```

Also the tool csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>dotnet_cqsgen</RootNamespace>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageType>DotnetCliTool</PackageType>
    <Version>1.0.3</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>    
</Project>
```

Though when I build the host project neither Hello world is written to console or text file is generated at c:\temp

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

```
  <Target Name="MyCliToolTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="dotnet cqsgen" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: That tool is never called. It's *defined* but never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like suggested by Panagiotis Kanavos you you also need to call the cli tool

```
  <Target Name="MyCliToolTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="dotnet cqsgen" />
  </Target>
```